# util-linux look with german umlauts

Tags: util-linux

I am currently having problems with util-linux's `look` in combination with German umlauts (`ä`, `ö`, `ü`). For testing purposes I set `LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8`.

Consider `german.dic`:

```
Aachen
Rindfleisch
```

in `UTF-8` encoding:

```
 $ file german.dic
german.dic: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

If I try to find the second word with `/usr/bin/look`, it works perfectly fine:

```
 $ look Rindf german.dic
Rindfleisch
```

Even if I add a word with a German umlaut (`ä`) inside the word `look` still works as expected:

```
 $ cat german.dic
Altäster
Rindfleisch
 $ look Rindf german.dic
Rindfleisch
```

**However**, if there is a word with a umlaut at the beginning:

```
 $ cat german.dic
Ältester
Rindfleisch
 $ look Rindf german.dic
```

It does not matter whether it's an uppercase or lowercase umlaut.

I've tried setting `LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8` (which is definitely installed on my system) too, which did not work.

Comment: The `util-linux` version of `look` (as shipped in Fedora) exhibits this problem, whereas the `bsdmainutils` version (as shipped in Debian) works as expected. It looks like a bug in the former...

Comment: `bsdmainutils` doesn't include `look` for me (Arch Linux). Is it named differently?

Comment: Distros ships one or the other, but not both; if Arch ships the `util-linux` `look`, it’s likely that its `bsdmainutils` package (or equivalent) doesn’t build it. (I haven’t checked.)

Answer (score 3):

Stephen Kitt suggested in a comment, that this bug does not appear in the `bsdmainutils`.

I am running

```
Linux archlinux 5.6.10-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat, 02 May 2020 19:11:54 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

with `util-linux` from June 2011.

In [the manpage for the bsd version of `look`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bsdmainutils/look.1.en.html#BUGS) the following is mentioned:

> Input files must be sorted with LC_COLLATE set to ‘C’.

There is no line about this in the util-linux manpage of `look`.

When sorting with `C` locale, the umlauts are escaped:

```
 $ LC_COLLATE=C sort german.dic
Rindfleisch
Ältester
ÖBB
```

(notice how I added a line starting with Ö for testing purposes).

If I try to `look` in this file, it works as intended:

```
 $ LC_COLLATE=C sort german.dic -o german.dic
 $ cat german.dic
Rindfleisch
Ältester
 $ look Rindf german.dic
Rindfleisch
 $ look Ält german.dic
Ältester
 $ look Ö german.dic
ÖBB
```

Thanks for the help!